# Error on click like page

Tags: facebook

I generate like button but when I click on like page it shows only error written kindly help me my code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Login with Facebook using PHP by CodexWorld</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #999999;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?ref=http://www.facebook.com/khappay.pk?ref=ts&fref=ts" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use the generator to create a proper code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Comment: I already use same link for code generator also try different way but can not success

Comment: No, the code generator does not misspell the parameter name.

Comment: what error would that be exactly?

Comment: after click on like it only showing error nothing else

Comment: The parameter name is `href`, not `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the link you are copying from facebook developer.

This one should works: Please check at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaibhavmule/nq9a17aa/2/)

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/khappay.pk&width=77&layout=button_count&action=like&size=small&show_faces=false&share=false&height=21" width="77" height="21" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkhappay.pk%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: again after click on like just error is types?? no error showing